# Fetch rows joined that don't match a query

Tags: sql

I have a an application with interns who can apply to internships.
We have a script that automatically qualifies the interns.
I would like to fetch all interns who aren't qualified to any internship.

The database is like this :

```
 Intern (Id,...)
 Application (Id, status, intern_id, internship_id,...)
 Internship (Id,...)
```

For the status, we have 'applied', 'qualified', 'current' and 'done'
Basically I need to do a join request of Interns who don't have Application with 'qualified' status, but my sql skills are pretty basic.

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that there can be several applications for an intern, an intern can only be qualified to one internship, but he can still be applying to another, so this won't work

```
SELECT *
FROM Intern i
INNER JOIN Application a ON i.Id = a.intern_id
WHERE a.status <> 'qualified'
```

Comment: can you show the query that you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the status in a `LEFT JOIN`, and filter for non-matches like so:

```
SELECT  ....
FROM    Intern i
        LEFT JOIN
                Application a
                ON i.Id = a.intern_id
                AND a.status = 'qualified'
WHERE   a.Id IS NULL
```

Substitute your list of columns, obviously!

Comment: That's elegant, and undestandable, plus it works like a charm. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
  FROM Intern i
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT *
       FROM Intern j
          , Application a
      WHERE j.id = a.intern_id
        AND i.id = j.id
        AND a.status = 'qualified')
```

Comment: I guess it works, but David M's solution feels a bit more clean to me. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Intern
WHERE Id IN ( SELECT Intern_id FROM Application WHERE status <> 'qualified' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should return what you're looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM Intern i
INNER JOIN Application a ON i.Id = a.intern_id
WHERE a.status <> 'qualified'
```

Obviously, you could replace the * with just the fields you were looking for. If you're looking for the interns that DIDN'T qualify, I wouldn't think you would need the Internship table. This does assume that there is only one application per intern... if that is not the case, you could use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Intern i
WHERE i.Id IN
(
 SELECT intern_id
 FROM Application a
 WHERE a.status <> 'qualified'
)
```